# mkproject: command not found

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to learn Flask

I want to use `mkproject` to generate the project.

> Virtualenvwrapper provides a "mkproject" command. It's the exact same as the mkvirtualenv command but it also creates a .project text > file in the root of the virtualenv which contains the dirpath of the > project source code.

I installed `virtualenvwrapper`

```
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

I add these commands on:

```
source "/usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh"
export WORKON_HOME="/opt/virtual_env/"
```

When I run the command

```
$ mkproject firstApp
```

I got this error

```
-bash: mkproject: command not found
```

am I missing something ?

Comment: This is not a Flask question, tags updated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [activate virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#introduction). Run this manually or put it in your `.bashrc`:

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: How Can I know what to put in WORKON_HOME= "??"