# mkproject: command not found in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, virtualenvwrapper

### Problem

I have a problem creating a virtualenvwrapper project in a shell script. When I create a project in shell all is ok. But a want to create it in a shell script.

Please help me to solve this problem.

I tried to find the answer. But it seems that no one had a trouble with creating virtualenvwrapper project in a shell script.

### My setup

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.
I have installed "virtualenvwrapper" package:

```
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

And wrote this lines into ~/.bashrc:

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/work/.envs
export PROJECT_HOME=~/work/projects
export VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

activated bash profile with:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

and created project dir:

```
$ mkdir -p $PROJECT_HOME
```

### Additional info

When I run:

```
type mkproject
```

in terminal it returns me:

```
mkproject is a function
mkproject () 
{ 
    typeset -a in_args;
    typeset -a out_args;
    ...[and more lines after]
}
```

when this command executed from script it returns this:

```
./setup2.sh: line 2: type: mkproject: not found
```

---

Command

```
$ ls -l setup2.sh
```

returns:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 name name 49 марта 23 12:55 setup2.sh*
```

### Creating project with shell script

After that I have created shell script (setup2.sh) with following lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkproject test_env
```

When I run this script by relative path:

```
$ ./setup2.sh
```

or aboslute path:

```
$ /home/name/env/setup2.sh
```

It says:

```
./setup2.sh: line 2: mkproject: command not found
```

### Creating project in shell

But when I run command which creates a project in a terminal:

```
$ mkproject test_env
```

all works fine

Comment: Did you set execution permissions to setup2.sh? Have you tried also with the absolute path within the script?

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio : Missing permissions on setup2.sh could not explain this error message. Using the absolute path is certainly a good idea.

Comment: Updated question. Tried to execute the script by absolute path and had the same error. Also added script permissions information.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902217/mkproject-command-not-found

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio Yes I have seen that link. When I type `mkproject proj_name` in terminal it works just fine. But when I run this command from shell script it fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be several causes for this, but I would first output $PATH inside your script and verify that it contains the directory where mkproject is supposed to be.

You should also verify that mkproject is indeed an executable, and not an alias or function, because functions are not exported by default. For this, run in your console the command

```
type mkproject
```

Comment: Updated the question. mkproject is a function. Command "whereis mkproject" does not return any path

Comment: @Nick: Well, then, if it is a function defined in the shell which runs in your console, you can't expect it to be available in a shell which runs a script....

Comment: @Nick : You **can** export a function to a subshell (`export -f mkproject`), but whether or not this makes sense, depends on your application. For example, if you make your script available to other people, this would not be a good design choice, because you would require all of them to also define the function in the shell from which they are calling your script, **and** export it. Maybe they don't even use *bash*, so this would not be a very user-friendly requirement.

Comment: @user1934428 thanks a lot! Your message made me a thought.The reason was that script ~/.bashrc doesn't run (it has commands that detect this and stop .bashrc execution) in non-interactive shells. That's why there were no mkproject command in script's shell. I have solved it. Now should I make a correct answer by myself? Sorry i'm new to stackoverflow

Comment: As the solution is trivial, once the reason for the problem is understood, you can also simply mark my response as the accepted answer.

Comment: @user1934428 But the text of your answer don't explain why mkproject couldn't be executed in shell script in this setup

Comment: I thought that this follows from the part of my answer, which says *verify that mkproject is indeed an executable, and not an alias or function*. But I agree, I should have said ***non-exported function***. I will edit my response accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple to execute `mkproject` in a shell script.  You just need to complete the same steps that make the function available to your interactive shell, namely sourcing your `~/.bashrc` script.

Just include this somewhere in your script:

```
source /PATH/TO/YOUR/.bashrc
```

Once you've done this, you can run `mkproject` as you usually do.

Note that if your script uses strict error checking like `set -e`, you will need to temporarily ease the error checking for the above plus any calls to `virtualenvwrapper` functions in your script, like:

```
set +e
source /PATH/TO/YOUR/.bashrc
set -e
```

and

```
set +e
mkproject WHATEVER
set -e
```

I'm not exactly sure why this happens, but the `virtualenvwrapper` functions return non-zero exit codes even for successful operations, which throws off the error-trapping convention completely.